# React.js - Best practice to calculate values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON, and in it there are some fields that I need to calculate.

Where is the best place to do it?

Currently I have set it in:

```
componentWillMount: function () {
  //Iterating over the JSON object
}
```

All my values are calculated and then the render is called. It works fine. I just wonder am I doing the right thing?

Comment: Yes. It's a normal pattern to put initial component operations in the constructor or in the componentWillMount (or componentDidMount if you need dom).

Comment: It depends. `componentWillMount` is only called once so if the data is static then that's fine. If you run the server it would be even better to do it there (in my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Are you mounting and umounting that component a lot? Are the calculations heavy?

What you are doing right now is probably fine, as you've said. If you really want to separate the data and calculations from the component you might want to look at [redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)

Comment: Is it a good practice to do all the heavy algorithm in `reselect`? I have a tournament scheduling app and I find it getting really slow at times. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do all your calculations in componentWillMount of your json.
You can then set the state accordingly because setting the state in componentWillMount wont cause a rerender infact your render method will receive the updated state.